# Retrieving data from crawler in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-crawler

I have a crawl data from a web page. I want to get some data from the HTML Code, how can I do that?

Some Example of crawl data:

```
<table width="272" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="floatleft" style="border-right:1px dotted #BFBFBF"> 
<tr> 
    <td width="130" class="paymentlabel"><strong>Transfer Fee</strong></td> 
    <td width="120"> $11 </td> 
    <td><a href="popups/whatsTDIT.php?type=1" class="whatsTDIT"><img src="http://i.i-sgcm.com/used_cars/qmark_red_18x18.png" width="18" height="18" /></a></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td class="paymentlabel" valign="top"><strong>Down Payment</strong></td> 
    <td> $47,444 (<a href="info_financial.php?ID=526494">change</a>) <p style="line-height:14px;"><span class="font_gray">Maximum 50% Loan</span></p> </td> 
    <td><a href="popups/whatsTDIT.php?type=2" class="whatsTDIT"><img src="http://i.i-sgcm.com/used_cars/qmark_red_18x18.png" width="18" height="18" /></a></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td class="paymentlabel"><strong>1st Instalment</strong></td> 
    <td> $901 </td> 
    <td><a href="popups/whatsTDIT.php?type=3" class="whatsTDIT"><img src="http://i.i-sgcm.com/used_cars/qmark_red_18x18.png" width="18" height="18" /></a></td> 
</tr> 
<tr bgcolor="#FFF4F4"> 
    <td class="paymentlabel" valign="top"><strong>Total</strong></td> 
    <td valign="top"> <strong class="font_red"> $48,356<br /><span class="font_gray" style="font-weight:normal;">(excluding insurance)</span> </strong> </td> 
    <td><a href="popups/whatsTDIT.php?type=4" class="whatsTDIT"><img src="http://i.i-sgcm.com/used_cars/qmark_red_18x18.png" width="18" height="18" /></a></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td class="font_gray font_10" colspan="3" style="padding:7px 0 7px 5px; line-height:12px;">Estimates based on 50% loan at 2.80% interest rate. <br />Check with seller for exact figure.</td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

Controller for crawler:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.UserAgent = "A .NET Web Crawler";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
return htmlText;
```

I want to get the value of Transfer Fee (i.e $11), value of Down Payment (i.e $47,444), value of 1st Instalment (i.e $901) and the value of Total (i.e $48,356). Is it possible to do that?? Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need a library the loads the html and allows you to query what you need. Try one or all of the following that allow you to do exactly that...

[CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery)

[Anglesharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp)

[Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com)